# I'm not sure if it's a normal issue, can everyone help me take a look

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image]
I'm not sure if it's caused by a normal error

The shadow on the left is the same as the grid, and carving it feels uncomfortable due to the jagged feeling,

The right side will be much smoother

It needs to be subdivided several times to make the left one smooth as well

This is the pants I made from Marvelous Designer

I don't know if anyone can help me see how to make the left and right sides equally smooth

My English is not  good. Thank you！

I uploaded a file：
https://file.kiwi/dc03ac07#evezknRlD5xLFZ8OdTFYsw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's due to the folds, the topology doesn't follow the shape of the folds, it creates this bad shading because the quads are very twisted. I guess there's no other solution but to give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier to add enough (virtual) topology, or you can smooth this part: Use the *Smooth* brush in *Sculpt* mode, or use a *(Deform) Smooth* modifier on the desired vertex group, but of course this solution tends to make the folds disappear:

[image]